# Ionic 2 - (window as any).resolveLocalFileSystemURL() throwing error

Tags: javascript, file, typescript, ionic-framework, window

I have some typescript code that uses the camera:

```
this.camera.getPicture(this.optionsGetCamera).then((imageURI) => {
    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
        this.crop.crop(imageURI, { quality: 100 }).then(newPath => {
            console.log(newPath);
            (window as any).resolveLocalFileSystemURL(newPath, function (fileEntry) {
                 this.readFile(fileEntry);
            });
        }).catch((error) => { ...
```

When I run the app, and use the camera function that gets used in this code, I get an error in the console (I am running on a device using the -lc parameter to view the log):

`console.error: ERROR -> 
            {"line":58535,"column":81,"sourceURL":"http://192.168.1.131:8100/build/main.js","__zone_symbol__currentTask":{"type":"microTask","state":"notScheduled","source":"Promise.then","zone":"angular","cancelFn":null,"runCount":0}}`

`line 58535` is this:

`window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(newPath, function (fileEntry) {`

This line is in the main.js file that gets created by ionic on build. I have been trying to understand `"source":"Promise.then"` as it seems like it might point to the problem (with a promise? or not using one?). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the **File** class from ionic native means The Typescript class 
don't use the javascript **any** type
refer https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {File} from 'ionic-native';

...

File.listDir(cordova.file.applicationDirectory, 
'mySubFolder/mySubSubFolder').then(
  (files) => {
    // do something
  }
).catch(
  (err) => {
    // do something
  }
);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! how would i set this up to have `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/57AFE969-7A54-4066-BFF7-AFEB0C6BFEB6/` be the folder I want to list the files for?

Comment: actually i think i just figured it out...i used `"file:///"` for the file system and `var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/57AFE969-7A54-4066-BFF7-AFEB0C6BFEB6/` for the folder.

Comment: prefer use environment folders like`Environment.SpecialFolder.<folderName>` +'your custom folder name'

Comment: for `var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/57AFE969-7A54-4066-BF‌​F7-AFEB0C6BFEB6/`? what environment/specialfolder is that in?

Answer (score 0):

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file` Worked for me that my code

```js
    getMedia(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          Camera.getPicture(this.options).then((fileUri: any) => {
            alert('File URI: ' + JSON.stringify(fileUri));
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL('file://' + fileUri, (fileEntry) => {
              alert('Type: ' + (typeof fileEntry));
              fileEntry.file((file) => {
                alert('File: ' + (typeof file) + ', ' + JSON.stringify(file));
                const fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.onloadend = (result: any) => {
                  alert('File Reader Result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                  let arrayBuffer = result.target.result;
                  let blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)], { type: 'video/mp4' });
                  const name = 'mypic'
                  this.upload(blob);
                };
                fileReader.onerror = (error: any) => {
                  reject(error);
                };
                fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
              }, (error) => {
                alert('File Entry Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
              });
            }, (error) => {
              alert('Error resolving file: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            });
          });
        });
      }
```